# Mongodb availability query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to find a query for room availability...My room  document is embedded in the hotel_info document and looks like that :

**Hotel_info:**

```
{
  "_id": "Hot_10",
  "Name": "Paris Hotel",
  "telephone": "0102030405",
  "Rooms": {
    "_id": "101",
    "Floor": "1",
    "Max_Pers": "4",
    "Room Type": "Bedroom",
    "Rate": "200"
  },  
}
```

And I have also a booking document that looks like that :

**Booking:**

```
{
  "_id": "22102015",
  "Name": "Jean",
  "Hotel_id": "Hot_10",
  "Room Number": "101",
  "Arrival Date": "Oct 22 2015",
  "Departure Date": "Oct 31 2015"
}
```

Maybe something like : get all occupied rooms from the booking document, then get all rooms from the hotel_info document and compare? or something like that.

Comment: So what is the basic criteria you use to determine if a room is available? From your question, I presume available rooms are those `Booking` documents which do not have `"Arrival Date"` fields or whose `"Departure Date"` equivalent 'date' value is less than or equal to the current timestamp, correct?

Comment: Available room are not yet in the booking document as the booking document is updated each time a customer book a room. So I guess the criteria will be based on rooms in the hotel_info document. But must also check that the same room in not booked for those dates...so another criteria is in the booking document...That's the trick...